# Clicking hyperlink and go to a frame (new window), how to do it?

Tags: php, frame

I am really knew to the frames; i have searched this questions in the internet but i didnt find any useful tutorials.

i have a website which shows links of other websites.currently i am not using any frames in my website. my website is made using php and code used for showing links is

```
echo("<a href=".$rows['url']." target="_blank">$rows['text']</a> </br>");
```

this code is working properly(when clicked the url will open in a **new window**).but what i want is to make a hyperlink like this website http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Dreamweaver-Tutorials-Free-Dreamweaver-Web-Design-Tutorials-and-Resource/69843  . when click to "view tutorials" it should go to a webpage with my website name and ads on top and the the other website in bottom. I know that it can be done by frames but what i dont know is how to link my hyper link to a frame (only for showing urls).

what i understood so far is that.

```
echo("<a href=web.php target="_blank">$rows['text']</a> </br>");
```

when an user click to this hyperllink it should go to **web.php** which is having below code.

```
<frameset rows="25%,75%">
   <frame src="index.php" />
   <frame src=<?php echo(".$rows['url']."?> />  <-- not sure about this code,i assumed that php can be inherited -->
</frameset>
```

but this code is not working. can any one tell me how i can hyperlink like the website "tutorialized.com" but in a new window.

Comment: Hey i have found the answer for my own query. I am writing the answer here for any future reference or uses for other users. If any one finds any error in this script please respond.This code worked for me.

what i have done is i have passed the link parameter to the url.
//starting//
    echo("<a href=web.php?u=".$rows['url']." target="_blank">$rows['text']</a> </br>");

//in **web.php**//
 

    <?php $u=$_GET['u'];?>
    <frameset rows="25%,75%">
       <frame src="index.php" />
       <frame src=<?php echo "$u";?> />  
    </frameset>

Comment: because i have less than 100  reputation i cant post my own answer in regular answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link should be like:

```
echo("<a href='http://somedomain.com/web.php' target='theNameOfTheFrame'>$rows['text']</a> </br>");
```

But make sure that the name for the frame is `theNameOfTheFrame`.